# Test ui-router and stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

This is my production code:

```
myApp.run ($rootScope, $location, AuthService, $state) ->
  $rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) ->
     $rootScope.stateChangeStarthasBeenCalled = true
          if toState.authenticate is true 
            $rootScope.authNecessaryButNotProvided = true
```

Part of my My router, where I set `authenticate` flat

```
  .state('auth.profile',
    url         : 'someURL'
    templateUrl : 'some.html'
    controller  : 'AuthController'
    authenticate: true
  )
```

I test like this:

```
it 'should have stateChangeStarthasBeenCalled defined', ->
    mockRootScope.$broadcast("$stateChangeStart", "event", "toState:auth.profile", "toParams", "fromState", "fromParams")
    expect(mockRootScope.stateChangeStarthasBeenCalled).toBeTruthy()    

it 'should have authNecessaryButNotProvided defined', ->
    mockRootScope.$broadcast("$stateChangeStart", "event", "toState:auth.profile", "toParams", "fromState", "fromParams")
    expect(mockRootScope.authNecessaryButNotProvided).toBeTruthy()
```

I want to check `toState` object , e.g. `toState.authenticate` which I defined in my routes.

So as a prerequisite, how to tell `stateChangeStart` the state we are changing to?

In production code works as expected, in test, not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually specify parameters for an event, they will be passed to the event handler:

```
mockRootScope.$broadcast(
    '$stateChangeStart',
    { name: 'auth.profile', authenticate: true }, // toState
    {}, // toParams                   
    {}, // fromState
    {}  // fromParams
);
```

They will appear in the same order, the first argument will be reserved for the `event` object though:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // ----------------------------------------^
    // first argument "event" is auto-generated
    console.log(toState.authenticate); // true
});
```

Comment: Edit: Not working! tostate.authenticate is not evaluating to "true" in my case. Any idea how access `toState.authenticate` from inside the test? `$rootScope.toState.authenticate` or `$state.toState.authenticate` is `undefined`. Also I am not completely happy with this solutino, since I would like to check ui-router's `authenticate` setting, instead on overriding it with `$broadcast`.

Comment: I've created a plunker for this solution here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WvlFQJkBWQLnQvDZrJwX?p=preview

Comment: I am not sure why do you need original value of `authenticate` property from router config, when the idea is (I suppose) to test how event handler works under various circumstances by manually specifying different parameters. Or do you want to test what value ui-router config has defined?

Comment: I see. I guess testing the event handling only and functionality if ui router works is good, so your approach it is.

Comment: Very nice demo, thanks friend! Will use it in my project.